# re-enter old data in database with foreign key

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys

So I have a table `employees` which have an `id`, `name` etc. `id` Is a primary key.

Another table, `certificates` is linked to table `employees` via a foreign key.

Now I need to insert old data into table `certificates`, of which some rows contain employee_id's that no longer exist in table `employees`. Naturally the foreign key constraint fails on this.

**My question is**: *Is there a way to set the foreign key to allow non-existing data to be 'referenced'?*

**Note**: the 'missing' employees have been moved to a table ex_employees, on request of the manager. I cannot change this.

Answer (score 0):

Try DISABLE KEYS or

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
make sure to

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;

Comment: Doesn't seem to work? `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;` executes nicely, but then I still can't insert the old data due to foreign key constraint.

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: `#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails` sorry for the late reply.